# Subdomains in App and Database

Tags: architecture, software-design, subdomain

My question is about software architecture, I'm really trying to focus more on this and less in coding, after all coding is just coding.

I have a website in which I would like to separate somehow the data, I mean , I need a database to store all the info related to the Business, I also need to store data to change / edit the content of my website (something like a CMS) and I would like to have a backend where to manage all the business logic but for this backend I also want to store its own data such as user and permissions (App Management tables).

What I'm trying to accomplish  is separate this sub-domains to be loosely coupled, where at any given time if I want I move the business table to another website or app without dragging with me the other tables ( App management tables and CMS tables) .

I think this is a good way to separates thing but I have no idea how to design it or code it, this is my first time trying to do something properly organized.

if anyone could point me out on the right direction , I'll be thankful.

Comment: Sub-domains are just URLs. It really depends on which CMS you are using.

Comment: I did not mean subdomain like subdomain.domain.com, I meant applications subdmains or applications components I think. I'm not using any CMS, I created my own website and I would like to have the ability to change some content every once in a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to separate your business data from your CMS/configuration data you could try to use two separate databases:

In the first data base you store the tables and relations which hold your business data. Depending on the amount of data you want to store and how often you (or your customers) will access these data, it could make sense to use a mature database technology (like a sql db) here. 
Depending on your use case, it might be necessary to access this database via an interface (e.g. per web service/webAPI) so that other applications (or websites) could access the business data.

The second database which will only keep your configuration or CMS data could even be realized as a local database (like sqlite or similar) as the data stored there will only be accessed from either your  website or your back office (and congruent access from many user is not very likely).

In that way your business data would be separated from your configuration data but all components (like your backoffice) could still access your business objects by calling the interface you provide for accessing your business database.